# Realm support for Swift 3

Tags: realm, swift3

So I updated to swift 3.0 and now my projects with realm 1.0.2 all give me an error.

**RealmSwift compiled with older version of Swift language (2.0) than previous files (3.0)**

I also tried to build a net new project and still get the build error, so I know it is not a conversion issue on the Swift side.

I found several Swift 3.0 beta users and tried to run the script to update my version to 3.0 and several other options. The last few posts appeared to use Cocoa Pods - which I don't currently use. Is that the supported fix path?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but here is what *should* work.

Essentially, the compiler gives you a description of what went wrong. The framework was compiled with Swift 2.0, while your project or other files were compiled with Swift version 3.0 (which means you made the switch after upgrading to the new version of Xcode.

To fix this, you need to use the Realm framework compiled with a Swift 3.0 compiler. Since the Realm team doesn't yet provide a precompiled version compiled with Swift 3.0, you have to do so yourself. To do that, go to their [Github repository](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa), and follow the instructions in the README under "Building Realm":

> **Prerequisites:**
>
> - Building Realm requires Xcode 7.3.
> - Building Realm documentation    requires jazzy
>
> Once you have all the necessary prerequisites, building
>   Realm.framework just takes a single command: `sh build.sh build`.
>   You'll need an internet connection the first time you build Realm to
>   download the core binary.

This should generate the Realm framework with the current compiler version, which you then just have to use to replace your current Realm framework with. After that, everything should compile as it used to.

---

As stated before, I don't know if this actually works, as I haven't tried it yet. I don't exactly know if Swift 3.0 is supported by Realm yet or if there are any other issues you could run into. So please let me know how this works out!

Comment: Based on what I've read this does appear to be the answer so I marked it as such. I however was unable to get it to work. I found a 28 step how to to update the realm to swift 3.0 as as well as what is in github. neither results in a product that works (I get multiple errors) but at this point I believe it is something I am doing wrong - I'll keep plugging away until I get it to work and or Realm releases their Swift 3 supported version.

Comment: @Undead-Earth.com you should refer to this guide https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3796